# How to set session & cookie in html?

Tags: html, cookies

I know some issue charset, refresh like

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
```

**Can I use like following code? Anyone can help me to give a suggestion**

```
<meta http-equiv="set-session" content="243242">
<meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="300">
```

Comment: [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) and [Cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php), but you need php

Comment: `set-cookie` is [possible, but non-conforming](https://w3c.github.io/html/document-metadata.html#statedef-http-equiv-set-cookie). Use a real HTTP header instead. "300"'s pretty meaningless though. content should contain name, value, expiry, path, domain etc.

Comment: You are absolutely right

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Javascript` to create / set cookie, such as

```
<script>
document.cookie = "username=Maidul Islam";
</script>
```

It is not possible to create / set `session` through `HTML` or `Javascript`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the [non-conforming `<meta>` property](https://www.metatags.org/meta_http_equiv_set_cookie), you would need either simple JavaScript or PHP, to set and read from cookies. This is a simple way to do it in PHP, although PHP requires some sort of server environment ([Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) for example) to run and execute scripts.

```
<?php

setcookie("name", "Maidul Islam");
echo "<p>Your name is " . $_COOKIE['name'] . ".</p>";

setcookie("date", "2018-01-21");
echo "<p>The date is " . $_COOKIE['date'] . ".</p>";

?>
```